# How are jivas (linga/sookshma sharirs) created as per Advaita?

Tags: philosophy, advaita, sankhya, jiva

As per advaita, jivas are nothing but Linga sharira or sookskhma sharira. This has been explained to me by user Pradip Gangopadhyaya before. But I need to know how are jivas created.

Advaita believes that the jiva (which is linga sharira or sookshma sharira) stops existing upon videha mukti. So if there's an end for the jivas, there must be a beginning too for the jivas.

Are jivas (sookshma shariras) created out of pancha mahabhutas or something else? ... If advaita doesn't deal with this topic then I'm sure that Samkhya philosophy must have discussed about the formation of the subtle body. An answer from a Samkhya perspective wouldn't be bad.

Please give a detailed answer, in a step by step manner, like which element existed first and what emerged from it and later which element was finally responsible for the formation of the subtle body.

Comment: jeeva is beginningless in advaita. Sri Shankara mentions this when criticizing the pancharatra doctrine in his brahmasutra bhashya.

Comment: But jiva is nothing but the subtle and causal sheaths that is destroyed on mukti after death. And so jiva too must have a beginning.

Comment: Brahman becomes jiva by maya which is anirvachaniya, ie inexplicable by words.So your Q does not have any answer i think

Comment: Jivas are not linga or sukshama sharira according to Advaita

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2423/when-and-how-the-atmas-were-created possible duplicate

Comment: @Pandya, Jivas ARE sookshma shariras. When the gross body dies, it is the JIVA or Sookshma sharira that travels to another physical body ... Even in the subtle state it remains as a jiva (under maya with all the impressions).

Answer (score 1):

Bhagwadgeeta has mention regarding it at 3.14 and 3.15 which says `living beings originate from God itself`.

**अन्नाद्भवन्ति भूतानि पर्जन्यादन्नसम्भव: |**

**यज्ञाद्भवति पर्जन्यो यज्ञ: कर्मसमुद्भव: || 14||**

**कर्म ब्रह्मोद्भवं विद्धि ब्रह्माक्षरसमुद्भवम् |**

**तस्मात्सर्वगतं ब्रह्म नित्यं यज्ञे प्रतिष्ठितम् || 15||**

> All beings are evolved from food; production of food is dependent on rain; rain ensues from sacrifice, and sacrifice is rooted in prescribed action. Know that prescribed action has its origin in the Vedas, and the Vedas proceed from the Indestructible (God); hence the all-pervading Infinite is  always  present  in  sacrifice. (14-15)

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2423/when-and-how-the-atmas-were-created

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly both Karana and Sukshma shareera have no beginning.

Sookshma Shareera is made of Mahapanchabhutas. Not the Panchikruta Pancha Bhutas which make the matter and world

Karana Shareera is made out of ignorance and also is same as Anandamaya kosha.

> So if there's an end for the jivas, there must be a beginning too for
> the jivas.

This is what Adi Shankara clearly says the opposite that things which were existent from beginning less time can stop existing.

> Vivekachudamani 198-199. Avidya or Nescience and its effects are
> likewise considered as beginningless. But with the rise of Vidyā or
> realisation, the entire effects of Avidya, even though beginningless,
> are destroyed together with their root – like dreams on waking up from
> sleep. It is clear that the phenomenal universe, even though without
> beginning, is not eternal – like previous non-existence.
>
> Notes: [Their root—i. e. Avidya.
>
> Previous non-existence—Pragabháva—a term of Hindu logic. When we say a
> thing comes into being at a definite point of time, we imply also that
> there was non-existence of that particular thing prior to the moment
> of its birth. And this ‘nonexistence’ is obviously beginningless. But
> it ceases as soon as the thing comes into being. Similarly, Avidya
> which means absence of Vidya or knowledge, even though beginningless,
> disappears when realisation comes.]
>
> [Reference](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vivekachudamani/d/doc144643.html)

Answer (score 0):

Like you see so many people the moment you start dreaming, similarly jivas came into existence. It was super imposition of self on non-self. Jivas have their existence only in the dream and not in reality. The exact answer probably needs the intellect to comprehend that which is the cause of the intellect. This is impossible. Hence it is not possible to completely comprehend how jeevas came into relative existence.